# Retrieve hex value from a file that is multiple bytes long (and reverse the hex digits)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose a location in a file at given offset is always 32 bits:

```
     | 00 01 02 03 04
-----|---------------
0x30 | 99 9E 36 00 AC
```

How would someone retrieve the hex value that spans multiple bytes (Case 1)? Now also given is the hex value needs to be reversed, the wanted outcome should be 0xAC00369E99   (Case 2).

What is either a fast, efficient or clean way to retrieve this value within Python?

Edit: This is the current way I do it

```
def hexAtOffset(path):

    with open(path, "rb") as file:
        content = file.read()
        pointer = 0x30
        hexString = ""
        for i in range (5):
            hexString += str(hex(content[pointer] ) )[2:]
            pointer+=1

    return hexString[::-1]

print (hexAtOffset() )
```

One problem I face here is that two zeros in 0x00 get shortened to 0x0

Comment: What is the *current* way you're doing it, and how do you think it's slow, inefficient or unclean? SO isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: Hello once again,

The current method I used is edited in the question now

Comment: Why do you want this? Seems pretty strange. What's your end goal?

Comment: In a FM patch toolset I'm writing, I want to support patch dumping from .vgm files. However, in the header I need to search for specific clock rates (the hex value in the problem) but it's stored differently for some specific things.

Comment: Hmm, I have no idea what that stuff is, but clock rate still rather sounds like a number to me, not like a hex string. Are you sure you don't want that number instead? I added a bit to my answer...

Comment: Ah, I see I indeed made a mistake here. It's an XY problem (I hadn't heard of this problem before) and _now_ it's fully correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
content[0x30:][:5][::-1].hex()
```

Demo:

```
>>> content = b'.' * 0x30 + b'\x99\x9e\x36\x00\xac' + b'.'
>>> content[0x30:][:5][::-1].hex()
'ac00369e99'
```

---

Though assuming this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)...

```
>>> int.from_bytes(content[0x30:][:4], 'little')
3579545
```

or

```
>>> struct.unpack('i', content[0x30:][:4])[0]
3579545
```

(Since you said "32 bits" and "clock rate" and apparently 3579545 Hz is a [somewhat popular clock rate](https://www.google.com/search?q=clock+rate+3579545)).